# Getting error when drawing polylines using python and opencv

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

I am getting this error:

> File "C:/Python27/drawingInTheVideo.py", line 22, in 
>       cv2.imshow('Frame 2', frame2) cv2.error: ........\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:261: error: (-215)
>   size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow

And i am using this code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('vid2.mp4')  # Open video file

while (cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()  # read a frame
    try:
        cv2.imshow('Frame', frame)
        frame2 = frame
    except:
        # if there are no more frames to show...
        print('EOF')
        break

    line1 = np.array([[100, 100], [300, 100], [350, 200]], np.int32).reshape((-1, 1, 2))
    line2 = np.array([[400, 50], [450, 300]], np.int32).reshape((-1, 1, 2))

    frame2 = cv2.polylines(frame2, [line1], False, (255, 0, 0), thickness=2)
    frame2 = cv2.polylines(frame2, [line2], False, (0, 0, 255), thickness=1)

    cv2.imshow('Frame 2', frame2)

    # Abort and exit with 'Q' or ESC
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break

cap.release()  # release video file
cv2.destroyAllWindows()  # close all openCV windows
```

What am i doing wrong? Please help

Comment: The image you're trying to show is empty

Comment: no, I don't think so.. I am assigning frame to frame2 so it can not be empty

Comment: Your program doesn't agree with you ;D

Comment: Where am i making a mistake then? @Miki

Comment: Are you saying that cv2.polylines doesn't return anything?

Comment: I'm saying that _"The image you're trying to show is empty"_. Use a debugger to see where is the issue. (There's nothing more I can do right now...)